# Login service Issue - Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to make login work, but there is some problem that I can't resolve.

I created login service and there I have:

```
Login(user: LoginModel) {

        return this.http.post(this.userLoginURL, user)  
            .pipe(map((response: Response) => {

               // this line needs changing to get response.token
               // if I write repsonse.token, it throws error because of type Response
                const token = sessionStorage.getItem('Token');

                if (token) {
                    this.token = token;

                    sessionStorage.setItem('Token', JSON.stringify(this.token));
                    return response;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            }));
    }
```

And in my component:

```
submitLoginForm(e) {

        if (this.valForm.valid) {
            this.loginService.login(this.loginModel)
                .subscribe(
                    (response) => {
                        this.router.navigate[('/dashboard')];
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                );
        }
    }
```

In my login service, in response I am getting the token that is an object with token and user inside:

```
token = {
  token = '...',
  user = {...}
}
```

How do I set the token to storage from this response? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a general response type, so you can access token property

```
Login(user: LoginModel) {

        return this.http.post(this.userLoginURL, user)  
            .pipe(map((response: any) => {

                const token = response.token;

                if (token) {
                    this.token = token;

                    sessionStorage.setItem('Token', JSON.stringify(this.token));
                    return response;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            }));
    }
```